# How to convert Dolby Vision HDR to HDR10+?

Tags: ffmpeg, iphone, hdr

I'd like to convert a file recorded from an iPhone 12 to a royalty-free version (for upload to Wikimedia, Flickr, etc). So the transfer involves:

| Source (iPhone proprietary-encumbered) | Destination (royalty-free) |
| --- | --- |
| 4k 60fps (UHD, not DCI) | 4k 60fps |
| BT.2020 in HLG (WCG) | BT.2020 in HLG (WCG) |
| Frame-level dynamic HDR metadata in Dolby Vision profile 8.4 | Frame-level dynamic HDR metadata in HDR10+ |
| HEVC | VP9 (open to AV1 as well but that's likely more nascent) |
| Bitrate is 31 Mb/s | Fine with higher bitrate to maintain same SSIM/PSNR |
| Audio is in AAC | Audio to Vorbis/OGG |

According to https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/ it should be possible to do most of this.
Anyone can help me cook up the right command for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to crack DRM?

Comment: What did you try with [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/)?  Something like `ffmpeg -i someFile.mp4  -c:a libvorbis -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 3.8M  outFile.webm` of course with `-b:v 3.8M` changed with the desired bitrate... Use container you like. There are trillion of options.  [Here](https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/)  a page with hdr10 examples (there are choices you need to make and you can't generalize too much). Do not forget the options for the hardware acceleration, when available.

Comment: @harrymc, not really. Videos shot by a user on their phone don't necessarily have 'DRM' in the traditional sense (like Netflix or HTML5 EME)

Comment: @Hastur, I've tried a bunch in ffmpeg docs, but didn't find luck. 1. Decoding DoVi's metadata is an issue. 2. Encoding HDR10+ (notice the plus)'s frame-level metadata is another issue that the Codecalamity link you shared also doesn't cover

Comment: I'd try [Mediacoder](http://mediacoderhq.com/) which is free for nc use. It has a GUI and a Wizard to help with settings. There's even a version for iphone/ipad

Comment: @MyPreciousss Following what they state in the section [Extracting and encoding with HDR10+ metadata](https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/#extracting-and-encoding-with-hdr10-metadata)... 2) _FFmpeg builds for Windows **now support HDR10+ metadata files by default**_ and the Linux one too, I suppose, else you can compile. And, if I correct understand, 1) _You will have to download a copy of hdr10plus_parser from quietviod’s repo._ to extract metadata into a `metadata.json` file that they use some lines later (Option 1).

Comment: @MyPreciousss Did you try [makemkv](http://makemkv.com)? BTW on GitHub there is [`dovi_tools`](https://github.com/quietvoid/dovi_tool). Give it a look to something like `dovi_tool -m 2  extract-rpu`...

Answer (score 1):

Although you have already posted and accepted a negative answer in
[How to convert Dolby Vision HDR to HDR10+?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33886/how-to-convert-dolby-vision-hdr-to-hdr10)
from 2021, there might exist a method for this conversion.

The recommended tool is ACES from
[DaVinci Resolve 18](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve).
This professional suite is free for personal use.

You will find a description of the method to use in the YouTube video
[Convert iPhone Dolby Vision to HDR10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReKxBGFac0g),
described as:

> Hi, in this video, I’m going to show you how to convert the iPhone 12
> and 13 series' rec2020 HLG (dolby vision) to rec2020 pq or HDR10, that
> is compatible with more devices like Roku or chromecast when uploading
> to YouTube.  I’ll be using ACES in DaVinci Resolve  to achieve this.
>
> Also in the end screen, I've included two videos that I made using
> this method, one being iPhone 12 Dolby Vision, the other was video
> from my iPhone 11 Pro shot in rec709 SDR.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this out before accepting it! 1. The video doesn't differentiate between HDR10+ (Plus) over regular HDR10 as the output. But maybe it outputs frame-level metadata seamlessly?

2. The creator ends up doing manual color grading on the video which won't work here as I want a process that allows anyone to batch-convert their years of various iPhone DoVi videos to HDR10+ equivalents using some 'standard' color transform possible (that works in *most* scenarios/usecases without manual tuning)

Comment: Ok, so that flow doesn't work for HDR10+ (regular HDR10 is trivial with ffmpeg)

Comment: Even though bounty got auto-awarded here, I don't believe this has solved my question. Maybe ACES is where its at and I need to iterate a bit to get to the final workflow.

Answer (score 1):

### ffmpeg

A command line as

```
ffmpeg -i someFile.mp4  -c:a libvorbis -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 3.8M  outFile.webm
```

will convert to

- `-c:v libvpx-vp9` VP9
- `-c:a libvorbis` Audio to Vorbis/OGG
- `-b:v 3.8M`  ~31 Mb/s, but you can change according to your wishes

not changing the original resolution nor the FPS.

#### HDR10+

As for HDR metadata in HDR10+, in the same link posted by the OP (in the updated section [Extracting and encoding with HDR10+ metadata](https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/#extracting-and-encoding-with-hdr10-metadata)), there is an explanation of how to extract the metadata and use it, for example, via the `dhdr10-info` option in x265-params.

> 1. Download download a copy of `hdr10plus_parser` from [quietviod’s repo.](https://github.com/quietvoid/hdr10plus_parser/releases)
> 2. Check your video has HDR10+ info that it can read
>
>    ```
>    ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i input.mkv -c:v copy -vbsf hevc_mp4toannexb -f hevc - | hdr10plus_parser --verify -
>    ```
> 3. Extract and save in the file `metadata.json`
>
>    ```
>    ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -vbsf hevc_mp4toannexb -f hevc - | hdr10plus_parser -o metadata.json -
>    ```
> 4. Use in your expression...
>
>    ```
>    ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -x265-params "colorprim=bt2020:transfer=smpte2084:colormatrix=bt2020nc:master-display=G(13250,34500)B(7500,3000)R(34000,16000)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,1):max-cll=1016,115:hdr10=1:dhdr10-info=metadata.json" -crf 20 -preset medium "output.mkv"
>    ```

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication about my question. The source video has DoVi metadata (not HDR10+ metadata). And I want to extract/convert DoVi->HDR10+ metadata for the file.

Thanks for helping out though!

Comment: Yep there was. BTW yours is not a single question... We should stick to a single-question single-answer to avoid (minimize) misunderstandings... BTW Did you try  [`dovi_tools`](https://github.com/quietvoid/dovi_tool). Give it a look to something like `dovi_tool -m 2  extract-rpu`...

Comment: Yeah, have checked out `dovi_tools` before. Here's an issue on that github tracking: https://github.com/quietvoid/dovi_tool/issues/23